# NodeJS: How to write a file parser using readStream?

Tags: node.js

I have a file in a binary format:

The format is as follows:

`[4 - header bytes] [8 bytes - int64 - how many bytes to read following] [variable num of bytes (size of the int64) - read the actual information]`

And then it repeats, so I must first read the first 12 bytes to determine how many more bytes I need to read.

I have tried:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file.bin');
readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {  ...  })
```

The problem I have is that chunk always comes back in chunks of 65536 bytes at a time whereas I need to be more specific on the number of bytes that I am reading.

I have always tried `readStream.on('readable', function() {   readStream.read(4)  })`
But it is also not very flexible, because it seems to turn asynchronous code into synchronous code because, I have to put the 'reading' in a while loop

Or maybe readStream is not appropriate in this case and I should use this instead? `fs.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd recommend as an abstract handler of a readStream to process abstract data like you're describing:

```
var pending = new Buffer(9999999);
var cursor = 0;
stream.on('data', function(d) {
  d.copy(pending, cursor);
  cursor += d.length;

  var test = attemptToParse(pending.slice(0, cursor));
  while (test !== false) {
    // test is a valid blob of data
    processTheThing(test);

    var rawSize = test.raw.length; // How many bytes of data did the blob actually take up?
    pending.copy(pending.copy, 0, rawSize, cursor); // Copy the data after the valid blob to the beginning of the pending buffer
    cursor -= rawSize;
    test = attemptToParse(pending.slice(0, cursor)); // Is there more than one valid blob of data in this chunk? Keep processing if so
  }
});
```

For your use-case, ensure the initialized size of the `pending` Buffer is large enough to hold  the largest possible valid blob of data you'll be parsing (you mention an int64; that max size plus the header size) plus one extra 65536 bytes in case the blob boundary happens just on the edge of a stream chunk.

My method requires a `attemptToParse()` method that takes a buffer and tries to parse the data out of it. It should return false if the length of the buffer is too short (data hasn't come in enough yet). If it is a valid object, it should return some parsed object that has a way to show the raw bytes it took up (`.raw` property in my example). Then you do any processing you need to do with the blob (`processTheThing()`), trim out that valid blob of data, shift the pending Buffer to just be the remainder and keep going. That way, you don't have a constantly growing `pending` buffer, or some array of "finished" blobs. Maybe process on the receiving end of `processTheThing()` is keeping an array of the blobs in memory, maybe it's writing them to a database, but in this example, that's abstracted away so this code just deals with how to handle the stream data.

Comment: It is interesting that even though our code does very similar things (collecting chunks of data in a buffer) the code and method calls are so completely different.  e.g. `d.copy()` vs. `Buffer.concat()`.

Comment: Right; I avoid `Buffer.concat()` since in this context there's no need to deal with both Arrays and Buffers; wrapping the growing Buffer in an array just adds a bit of overhead, plus the `concat()` method says it has to loop through the buffers twice if no length is given, so probably using the `copy()` method, with a pointer to keep your place is the better performance method, though I haven't checked for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Add the chunk to a Buffer, and then parse the data from there.  Being aware not to go beyond the end of the buffer (if your data is large).  I'm using my tablet right now so can't add any example source code.  Maybe somebody else can?

Ok, mini source, very skeletal.

```
var chunks = [];
var bytesRead= 0;

stream.on('data', function(chunk) {

   chunks.push(chunk);
   bytesRead += chunk.length;

   // look at bytesRead...
   var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
   chunks = [buffer];  // trick for next event
      // --> or, if memory is an issue, remove completed data from the beginning of chunks
   // work with the buffer here...

}
```

Comment: how do you add the chunk to a buffer? Do I have to keep a buffer variable somewhere and wait for the next data event? e.g. if for example, I need to read 12 bytes and then I find out that I need to read 100k bytes and the chunk is 60k long, do I need to wait for the next data event to append it to the buffer.

Comment: See edited answer.  Yes, if data is 100k you'd have to wait for more data events.  Hope that gets you started

Comment: so chunks will just keep growing to one big massive array??

Comment: In this simplistic example, yes.  Smarter code would remove completed data from the beginning of chunks[].  (And keep an offset)